# Checking if a value is already in a List won't work

Tags: java, arraylist

I am doing a small program that holds shelves in a library list. If the number of shelf was already entered before, you can't enter it again. However, it's not working.

Here is my code in the main class:

```
    Shelf s = new Shelf(1);
    Shelf s2 = new Shelf(1);
    Library l = new Library();
    l.Addshelf(s);
    l.Addshelf(s2);
```

As you can see I entered 1 in both objects as the shelf number so this code below should then run from the library class

```
public void Addshelf(Shelf s)
{
    List li = new ArrayList();
    if(li.contains(s))
    {
        System.out.println("already exists");
    } else {
      li.add(s);
    }
}
```

The problem must be in the above method. I want to know how I check if that shelf number already exists in the list, in which case it should prompt me with the above statement - "already exists.

Comment: You have taken `List li = new ArrayList();` to be a local variable of method `Addshelf(Shelf s)` so every time you call this method a new list will be created. It doesn't server your purpose. You need to make your List an instance variable or class variable as per your need.

Comment: Thanks a lot all I had to do therefore was move the List outside the method. Thanks all for your help !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to override `equals` method in `Shelf` in order to get the behavior you desire.

Without overriding `equals`, `ArrayList::contains`, which calls `ArrayList::indexOf`, would use the default implementation of `Object::equals`, which compares object references.

```
@Override
public boolean equals (Object anObject)
{
    if (this == anObject)
        return true;
    if (anObject instanceof Shelf) {
        Shelf anotherShelf = (Shelf) anObject;
        return this.getShelfNumber() == anotherShelf.getShelfNumber(); // assuming this
                                                                       // is a primitive
                                                                       // (if not, use equals)
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Here's an article on how to do that: http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/overriding-equals-method-in-java/

Comment: i did the equals method in shelf now should i change the above Addshelf method in any way?

Comment: what I did is create both hashcode and equals method but somehow it's still not detecting that I have entered the same shelf number twice.
   
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (obj == null) {
            return false;
        }
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass()) {
            return false;
        }
        final Shelf other = (Shelf) obj;
        if (this.shelfnum != other.shelfnum) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

Comment: @user3679986 Is shelfnum's type primitive?

Comment: it's fixed now, all i had to do is move the list outside the method and it worked thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the Javadoc for List at the `contains` method you will see that it uses the `equals()`method to evaluate if two objects are the same. So you have to override the method `equals` on your `Shelf` class.

Example:

```
public class Shelf
{
    public int a;  

    public Shelf (int x)
    {
        this.a= x;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object object)
    {
        boolean isEqual= false;

        if (object != null && object instanceof Shelf)
        {
            isEqual = (this.a == ((Shelf) object).a);
        }

        return isEqual;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you have `override` `equals()` method in `Shelf`.

From `Java` [doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#contains%28java.lang.Object%29). How `contains()` works?

> Returns true if this list contains the specified element. More
>   formally, returns true if and only if this list contains at least one
>   element e such that (o==null ? e==null : o.equals(e)).
>                                                 ^^

Answer (score 0):

Try overriding methods hashCode() and equals(Object obj) in your Shelf class and then call contains.

[Equals and HashCode tutorial](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-collections/hashcode-equals.html)